# Раскидать записи в строках в Excel по колонкам

Tags: excel

В Excel есть строки типа

```
ans
Свистка$Салюта$Поцелуя
План$Бредень$Динамит
цилиндр$конус$пирамида
пенсне$бинокль$монокль
```

Т.е. в каждой строке есть по три выражения, разделенных знаком $. Можно ли автоматизированно сделать чтобы эти выражения в итоге оказались в колонках ans1, ans2, ans3 так

```
ans1          ans2           ans3
Свистка       Салюта         Поцелуя
План          Бредень        Динамит
цилиндр       конус          пирамида
пенсне        бинокль        монокль
```

Comment: возможно вам нужно [это](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо